# Nominatim installation - network flood

Tags: openstreetmap, network, nominatim

I've tried to install Nominatim with a planet.pnf file to a server which is hosted at Dacentec(36gb ram, 16 threads, 1x2TB 7200 RPM hard).
The installation was going well, it was already indexing data at Rank 26, when suddenly the server was remotely shut down. I"ve received the following message from Dacentec

> Your server with IP x.x.x.x has been flooding the network with traffic in excess of 833315000 bits/sec and 109198 packets/sec. This server has been shutdown.

What could have been the problem? I tought that indexing the data shouldn't even require network access, am I wrong in this matter?

As the server was rented Monday, and only the Nominatim installation ran on it, I am totally buffled by this issue.

Since then I've learned that the traffic was outgoing traffic.

Comment: Are you running the database and application of the same server?

Comment: crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781025/nominatim-server-shut-down-because-of-flood